# Include specific attribute or child-element text in breadcrumb rendering

Tags: oxygenxml

Within the author it displays a breadcrumb, and [I know you can modify its display to either some other static text or localisation](https://www.oxygenxml.com/doc/versions/20.1/ug-editor/topics/rendering-elements-cc-author.html#rendering-elements-cc-author__configuration_file), but I'm wondering if it's possible to dynamically show an attribute, or execute some other context-specific xpath dynamically.

---

As a test I can change the breadcrumb using the localisation editor variable [`${i18n()}`](https://www.oxygenxml.com/doc/versions/20.1/ug-editor/topics/editor-variables.html#editor-variables__localization).

<sub>**`cc_config.xml`**</sub>

```xml
<elementRenderings platform="webapp">
    <render element="num" as="${i18n(test)}" annotation="${i18n(test)}"/>
```

<sub>**`translation-cc.xml`**</sub>

```xml
<key value="test">
    <comment></comment>
    <val lang="en_US">Year</val>
```

"Year" is actually a `num` element.
[image]

---

However, trying any other variable, even 'more static' ones like `${cf}` or `${tp}` simply render the variable text literally, instead of evaluating it.

<sub>**`cc_config.xml`**</sub>

```xml
<elementRenderings platform="webapp">
    <render element="paragraph" as="${xpath_eval(./@eId)}" annotation="${xpath_eval(./@eId)}"/>
    <render element="p" as="${tp}" annotation="${tp}"/>
```

(paragraphs do have an `eId` attribute) [image]

---

As you can see, I tried using `annotation`; but these tooltips also simply display the variable literally.
I also fiddled and tried a bunch of xpath stuff, like `@eId`/`.@eId`/`/@eId`, but I think there's some restriction in using the Content Completion Configuration File with respect to editor variables.

So is the thinking right but I am doing something wrong, or is it not the right way but there is some other way to affect the breadcrumb? Maybe with the schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element display names in `cc_config.xml` file do not support most of the editor variables. Most of them, like `${cf}` (current file) and `${tp}` (total number of pages) don't make sense to be used when rendering the name of an element.

The `xpath_eval` would make sense - the display name of an element may depend on its attributes (e.g. the `@id` attribute), it's index in the document (e.g. 'Section 3'), etc. We have a feature request registered for this case and I added your vote to it.

As a partial workaround you can use a JS API to compute the display name of the element based on the element original name and its attributes:

```
goog.events.listen(workspace, sync.api.Workspace.EventType.BEFORE_EDITOR_LOADED, function(e) {
  e.options.elementNameEnhancer = function(elemName, attrs) {
    var displayString = elemName;
    var attr = attrs['id'];
    if (attr) {
      displayString += ' (#' + attr.attributeValue + ')';
    }
    return displayString;
  };
});
```